# OpenGL does not work properly on Ubuntu 14.04 with Mesa 10.1.3

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, opengl, 3d, nouveau

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to 14.04 and I'm now experiencing problems with some software that uses OpenGL. Instead of rendering images it renders just black screen.

I know that libglew and GLX extension are used for context creation.

glxinfo with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose outputs the following:

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 10de:0fc6, driver nouveau
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_nouveau(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_nouveau
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/alexey/.drirc: No such file or directory.
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NVE7
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

It is also strange that a lot of other graphical applications work properly (like meshlab).

Could anyone help me with that? I know little about 3D graphics in Linux, so please advise if I need to provide more information.

**Update:**
lspci -v output for GPU:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3553
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: What graphics and drivers are you using? (Use `lspci -v`)

Comment: Updated the post. I did not install any proprietary drivers, want this to work with standard 14.04 mesa installation if possible.